# submit model with RenderPartial on View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So imagine this:

There is a View.
There is a model with this view in the following form:

```
Id
List<Food>
```

within each Food, there is:

```
Id
Name
List<Ingredients>
```

each ingredient contains:

```
Id
Name
Qty
```

This is in 1 model.

I have a view which takes in this Model. 
I then have a partial view which takes in the List and renders it on the screen.
That works however when the form is submitted (the button is on the main view), the data fails to bind/is not shown in the Model.

what is the correct way to be able to bind the data back?

it does work when I take the whole thing and put it in the main view itself but due to reusability reasons, it makes sense having it in a partial view so I can just "drop" it on any page and pass the data.

The partial view takes in this:

```
@model List<FoodProject.Web.Models.FoodViewModel>
```

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried using the EditorTemplate and it seems to **almost** respect the model binding conventions as before using the Html.Partial was not doing so. That was producing things like:

```
[0].PropertyName
```

instead of:

```
ModelName[0].PropertyName
```

The template editor is almost there but gives me:

```
ModelName.[0].Id
```

I believe this is why when posting, I get null back in the model collection
how can I make it respect the model binding? where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be close with the Editor Template because that worked for me.  I'll show my example and maybe it will help you see what you have wrong.

The Models:

```
public class TestModelA
{
    public List<TestModelB> PropA { get; set; }
}

public class TestModelB
{
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}
```

The Editor Template (*TestModelB.cshtml*) placed in *Views/Shared/EditorTemplates*:

```
@model MvcTest.Models.TestModelB
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PropB)
```

The main view:

```
@model MvcTest.Models.TestModelA
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PropA)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```